# To store a int in an String in C#

Tags: c#, string, int, store

How can I store a int value into a string ?
Like

```
code = Self.textField.text;
```

I would appreciate it if anyone would help me.

Comment: What have you tried? https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+convert+into+to+string

Comment: What is `code`? What is `Self` (did you mean `this`)?

Comment: No its self in xCode its some kind of modified c#

Answer (score 4):

> How can I store a int value into a string?

Based your example, I think your real question is; *How can I store a string value into an int?*

You can't store a `string` in an `int`. This doesn't make sense at all. But you can convert to your `string` to `int`.

For example;

```
int code;
if(Int32.TryParse(Self.textField.text, out code))
{
  // Your string can be parsed to int.
}
else
{
  // Your string can't parsed to int.
}
```

By the way, [`Int32.TryParse(String, Int32)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses current culture thread with [`NumberStyles.Integer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) style. That means your string can have only;

- Leading white space.
- Trailing white space.
- Leading positive or negative sign.

If you want to parse specific style with your specific culture thread, you can use [`Int32.TryParse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Int32)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can:

```
int intVariable = 0;
string stringVariable = "0";

stringVariable = intVariable.ToString(); // convert int to string
intVariable =  int.Parse(stringVariable); // convert string to int
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how can you parse a numeric string into an integer value?  Something like this:

```
var code = 0;
if (!int.TryParse(Self.textField.text, out code))
{
    // numeric parsing failed, handle the error condition
}
// if parsing succeeded, here "code" has the numeric integer value
```

Answer (score 0):

A string is a string, an int is an int, but you can check and see if your string value contains numbers.

```
  string intValue = "1";
```

You can check it has an int in it using:

```
  int parsedValue = 0;
  if (int.TryParse(intValue, out parsedValue))
  {
       ....
  }
```

Comment: Its like there is an textfield where the user has to enter the right number(code) and if the number matches with the code it switches to the other side of the app. So the string is always a number .